# TensorFlow vectorized map with argmax has not a converter, how to add it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, for-loop, vectorization

I have developed a `tf` function (`tf version 2.1`):

```
@tf.function
def make_xcorr(T, S, sigma_S, outshape):
    ...
    xcorr = ... #combination of T and S
    sigma_xcorr = ... #combination of T, S and sigma_S


    def bootstrap(iter):
        _xcorr = tf.random.normal(outshape, xcorr, sigma_xcorr)
        _maxidxs = tf.math.argmax(_xcorr, axis=1) #shape (batch)
        return _maxidxs

    maxidxs = tf.vectorized_map(bootstrap, np.arange(100))
    return maxidxs
```

This function is called within a `forloop`:

```
def main():
    ...
    for i in range():
        ...
        out = make_xcorr(...)
        ...
```

The idea is to execute 100 times the boostrap operation within the `tf function`. I have also tried with `tf.map_fn` instead of `tf.vectorized_map`, it actually works, but I would like to try if there is a speedup with the usage of `tf.vectorized_map`, but I get the follow error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Note that RandomStandardNormal inside pfor op may not give same output as inside a sequential loop. 

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                     File "/home/gangora/scripts/make_cross_correlation_testgpu.py", line 1018, in main_make_cross_correlation_testgpu         xcorr, maxidxs, sigma_xcorr, _maxidxs = make_xcorr_err1(flux_template_vec, data_partial, sigma_partial, (end-start, vec_z.shape[0]))                                                                                                          File "/home/gangora/anaconda3/envs/angora_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py", line 568, in __call__                                                                                                    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)                                                                                    File "/home/gangora/anaconda3/envs/angora_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py", line 615, in _call                                                                                                       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "/home/gangora/anaconda3/envs/angora_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py", line 497, in _initialize
    *args, **kwds))
  File "/home/gangora/anaconda3/envs/angora_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 2389, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/gangora/anaconda3/envs/angora_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 2703, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/gangora/anaconda3/envs/angora_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 2593, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "/home/gangora/anaconda3/envs/angora_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 978, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/home/gangora/anaconda3/envs/angora_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py", line 439, in wrapped_fn
    return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/gangora/anaconda3/envs/angora_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 968, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in converted code:

    /home/gangora/scripts/make_cross_correlation_testgpu.py:764 make_xcorr_err1  *
        _maxidxs = tf.vectorized_map(bootstrap, np.arange(100))#, parallel_iterations=100, back_prop=False, swap_memory=True, infer_shape=False )
    /home/gangora/anaconda3/envs/angora_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/parallel_for/control_flow_ops.py:394 vectorized_map
        return pfor(loop_fn, batch_size)
    /home/gangora/anaconda3/envs/angora_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/parallel_for/control_flow_ops.py:189 pfor
        return f()
    /home/gangora/anaconda3/envs/angora_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/parallel_for/control_flow_ops.py:183 f
        return _pfor_impl(loop_fn, iters, parallel_iterations=parallel_iterations)
    /home/gangora/anaconda3/envs/angora_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/parallel_for/control_flow_ops.py:256 _pfor_impl
        outputs.append(converter.convert(loop_fn_output))
    /home/gangora/anaconda3/envs/angora_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/parallel_for/pfor.py:1280 convert
        output = self._convert_helper(y)
    /home/gangora/anaconda3/envs/angora_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/parallel_for/pfor.py:1460 _convert_helper
        (y_op.type, y_op, converted_inputs))

    ValueError: No converter defined for ArgMax
    name: "loop_body/ArgMax"
    op: "ArgMax"
    input: "loop_body/random_normal"
    input: "loop_body/ArgMax/dimension"
    attr {
      key: "T"
      value {
        type: DT_FLOAT
      }
    }
    attr {
      key: "Tidx"
      value {
        type: DT_INT32
      }
    }
    attr {
      key: "output_type"
      value {
        type: DT_INT64
      }
    }

    inputs: [WrappedTensor(t=<tf.Tensor 'loop_body/random_normal/pfor/Add_1:0' shape=(100, 30000, 3000) dtype=float32>, is_stacked=True, is_sparse_stacked=False), WrappedTensor(t=<tf.Tensor 'loop_body/ArgMax/dimension:0' shape=() dtype=int32>, is_stacked=False, is_sparse_stacked=False)].
    Either add a converter or set --op_conversion_fallback_to_while_loop=True, which may run slower
```

The traceback seems to suggest to add a converter to the argamx function, but I really don't know how to implement such converter. I can also try to set `--op_conversion_fallback_to_while_loop=True`, if the code doesn't not slow down, but I don't know where set this field.

So, summarizing, my question is:
**How can I add a converter to a tensorflow operation like argmax?**

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem as a oneliner: 
`tf.map_fn(lambda x: (tf.roll(x[1], axis=0, shift=x[0][0])), (tf.expand_dims(tf.range(0, 10, delta=1), -1), a), dtype=tf.float32)`
vs
`tf.vectorized_map(lambda x: (tf.roll(x[1], axis=0, shift=x[0][0])), (tf.expand_dims(tf.range(0, 10, delta=1), -1), a))`